# Cocoa touch: decorating text

Tags: cocoa-touch, text, fonts

I've added a UIAppFont to my plist, and, happily, am able to write a custom font to my display.

Now, if I had to display this custom font in a very large size with a yellow outline and purple in the middle- how in the world would I achieve that??

Answer (score 0):

`NSAttributedString` is available on iOS 3.2/4.  Maybe that’s what you’d like to try.  The [NSAttributedString Application Kit Additions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000167-SW6) has all the constants that are available.

Comment: Thanks, Evadne.  It doesn't get me what I need, so I'm resorting to pngs and a kern table.